# isset request from input

Tags: php, laravel

In Laravel, I'm sending data from form to controller and I would like to check if date field has been set. 
This piece of code does not work:

```
if(isset($request->input('date')))
```

Comment: for validation purposes?

Comment: you get any error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on Laravel [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input), You can use Laravel default given `has()` method to determine if a value is present on the request. The has method returns true if the value is present and is not an empty string.

You can also try this:

```
if(isset($request->date) && !empty($request->date)){

// Your code


}
```

**OR**

```
if(isset($request->date) && count($request->date) > 0){

    // Your code


    }
```

Comment: thats a super slow way to go arownd a simple task! if(!empty(request('date')) will do the trick just fine!

Comment: Laravel builtin `$request->has()` method is shorter and simpler.

Answer (score 9):

Use the following code :

`if($request->has('date'))`

If you want to validate your form fields you can use laravel validation.

See https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/validation

Comment: Very bad answer! You should use the has method to determine if a value is present on the request. The has method returns true if the value is present !! and is not an empty string!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($request->input('date'))){
  //your code
}
```